# Formulário não submete por causa de comando $("#div").attr("disabled",true); do jquery. O que fazer para resolver?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#button").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#button").animate({opacity:0.2});

    var nome    = $("#nome").val();
    var telefone    = $("#tel").val();
    var email   = $("#email").val();
    var onde    = $("#onde").val();
    ......         
)};
```

No IE e Firefox funciona de boa, quando clico no botão ele envia os dados via jquery para uma página e tem que desabilitar o botão, mas não envia os dados quando é pelo google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque um `setTimeout` de 1 milissegundo na ação de bloquear o botão:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        btn.attr('disabled',true);  
    },1);
   //...
});
```

Desta forma ele não interrompe o envio do `form` mas ainda assim se bloqueia rapido o bastante para evitar mais cliques do usuário.

[**`Exemplo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/fD42K/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Porque não usa o evento de `onsubmit` do form para realizar o bloqueio?

```
$("#form").submit(...);
// Ou
$("#form").on('submit', (function(){
    $("#button").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#button").animate({opacity:0.2});

    var nome    = $("#nome").val();
    var telefone    = $("#tel").val();
    var email   = $("#email").val();
    var onde    = $("#onde").val();
    ......
)};
```

Acredito que esse comportamento esteja correto, mas não é coerente para todos os browsers...

É certo que se desabilitar o `button` que submete o form ele não irá submeter.
Acredito que usar o evento de `onsubmit` é mais certo porque ocorre durante o `submit` e não corre o risco de bloquear o `submit`.

De uma olhada na documentação jQuery para o evento de [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).